# Xwindows becomes unresponsive

Tags: 14.04

On my computer after a moment of use xwindows becomes unresponsive. Can't type anything or interact at all. I checked the processes with the ps command and it once said compiz was 79% CPU. I restarted the environment and after a short while it became unresponsive. This time compiz was only 4%. Checking the memory however I was pretty much all full. PS didn't give any hint to what is using the resources. What is going on?

Comment: How much memory? How much swap? `free -h;swapon` will tell you.

Comment: @waltinator don't know what you were trying to so with the swapon command. It just gave swapon help. This is the output when my computer is starting to grind to a halt, but still responds if patient. MEM TOTAL 3.8G USED 3.7 FREE 109M SHARED 55M BUFFERS 883M CACHED 1.5G SWAP TOTAL 255M USED 616K FREE 255M

Answer (score 0):

Been a while. Turns out I have a wubi installation. I generally attribute all my issues to this and have stopped using it.